# Segmentation fault while creating an adjacency list

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I am creating an adjacency list for the graph structure.Below is my code snippet which
 is giving "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0x0040340f in       std::_List_node_base::hook ()" error when I run in gdb. Could somebody please point out the error in the code.

```
struct graph{
    list<int> vertex;
}*v;

list<int>::iterator it;
cin>>num_vertices;

v = new  graph[num_vertices];

if (v == 0)
    cout << "Error: memory could not be allocated";

for(i=1;i<=num_vertices;i++)
{
    cin>>num_connected;
    for(j=1;j<=num_connected;j++)
    {
        cin>>m;
        (v+i)->vertex.push_back(m);
    }
}
for(i=1;i<=num_vertices;i++)
    for(it= (v+i)->vertex.begin();it!= (v+i)->vertex.end();it++)
        cout<<*it<<"->";
```

Comment: Did you try to run it step by step in gdb to see which line causes the error?

Comment: You can use `backtrace` or simply `bt` in gdb to see the calls which led to your error. And don't use `v+i`, use `v[i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ arrays are zero-based so should be indexed using `[0]` to `[num_vertices-1]`.  If you change your loops to go from 0 to num_vertices-1

```
for(i=0;i<num_vertices;i++)
```

your code should work.

The current failures are presumably caused by the last iteration of the loops dereferencing `(v+num_vertices)` which is memory beyond your array.  Writing to memory you haven't allocated gives undefined behaviour so a seg fault wouldn't be surprising.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong here, I compiled your program (just declared the variables you are using) and it works fine

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

struct graph{
        list<int> vertex;
}*v;

int main ()
{
    int num_vertices = 0;
    int num_connected = 0;

    list<int>::iterator it;
    cin>>num_vertices;

    v = new  graph[num_vertices];

    if (v == 0)
        cout << "Error: memory could not be allocated";

    for(int i=0;i<num_vertices;i++)
    {
        cin>>num_connected;
        for(int j=1;j<=num_connected;j++)
        {
            int m;

            cin>>m;
            (v+i)->vertex.push_back(m);
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<num_vertices;i++)
        for(it= (v+i)->vertex.begin();it!= (v+i)->vertex.end();it++)
            cout<<*it<<"->";

}
```

Comment: The code does not works if I initialize i loop from 1 instead of 0 http://ideone.com/S18Ky9

Comment: @rishabh, that's right because array indecies run [0,n) not [1,n]

Comment: thanks for pointing out the error.I would be glad if you could tell me whether this is a good way for making an adjacency list ?

Comment: @rishabh, this is entirely different question, post it separately